# Plotting a distribution that is returning in error-in r

Tags: r, plot, poisson

anyone know what this error message means? I am trying to plot this distribution. I've used the code in another project and it works, I just can't tell why its doing this or what it means.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Your code works for me! Maybe it is an issue with any package!

Comment: Please edit your question to post your code as text (cut-and-paste, in code format [indent or triple-backquote]) rather than as a screenshot ...

Answer (score 2):

Based on googling your error message, and finding [this R-help message from 2010](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-November/259918.html), I'd guess that you have a PDF device open.  Try running `dev.off()` until you get `null device 1`, then try again.

Or, when in doubt, restart your R session. https://www.cipher-it.co.uk/have-you-tried-turning-it-off-and-on-again/